# Aurelia Binding errors ( on browser console)

Tags: aurelia

I am using below snippet in html

```
value.two-way="lstName.IsBlocked ? 'Blocked' : Value2 + ' %'"
```

on console it shows error as
Uncaught Error: Binding expression

```
"lstName.IsBlocked?'Blocked':Value2+' %'" cannot be assigned to.
at b.a.assign (aurelia.js?v=1.0009:59)
at a.updateSource (aurelia.js?v=1.0009:61)
at a.call (aurelia.js?v=1.0009:61)
at a.v [as callSubscribers] (aurelia.js?v=1.0009:58)
at a.notify (aurelia.js?v=1.0009:60) `
```

What can be the reason for this ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `two-way` binding, the binding expression needs to be assignable.

As the error says: `"lstName.IsBlocked?'Blocked':Value2+' %'" cannot be assigned to.`. If your bound property changes from the view, it would have to be able to write back to the expression and update the source value in your view model. You can't really write to an inline if.

Change `two-way` to `to-view` and it should work.

#### EDIT:

Since you *need* the expression to be writable, you could use a ValueConverter to solve the problem (assuming `Value2` is what you want to write to):

```
export class BlockedValueConverter {
    toView(value, isBlocked) {
        return isBlocked ? 'Blocked' : value + ' %';
    }

    fromView(value) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then in your html (don't forget to `require` the valueConverter or use `globalResources`):

```
value.two-way="Value2 | blocked:lstName.IsBlocked"
```

Comment: Thanks for insight.  This did not help. To be more specific. Error is thrown when we try to edit the textbox.

Comment: If you need it to be writable, you need to change the structure. Think of it this way: say `lstName.IsBlocked` is `true` and you edit the textbox, what do you expect to happen? Theoretically, the value would need to be written to the literal string `'Blocked'` which is of course not possible. You should use a ValueConverter to do this. I've updated my answer with an example.